# Executing System.Diagnostics.Process cmd.exe only opens command prompt, doesn't execute arguments

Tags: c#, command-line, process, command-line-arguments, system.diagnostics

Where am I going wrong with this? It's like the arguments are not even getting executed, it just opens the command prompt, and that's it. The "results" (StandardOutput) is exactly what shows up when you just open a new command prompt....says Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600] Copyright...blah then the path where the command prompt is starting from.

Anyway, here's the code that I have:

```
    private static void ExecuteProcess(string processFile, string processArguments)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(processFile, processArguments);
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        //psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;

        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            p.Start();

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

            if (p.ExitCode == 0)
                MessageBox.Show(output, "Results");
            else
                throw new Exception(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            p.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

processFile is equal to "cmd.exe"
processArguments is equal to:

```
csvde -s {servername} -f {filename} -d OU=MyOU,DC=dmz,DC=lan -r "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)" -n
```

Any help as to why the "arguments" aren't getting executed would be great!

Edit:

One thing I've found so far, Chris's suggestion about the permissions is true, I needed to set:

```
psi.Verb = "runas";
```

But when executing the process it didn't look like there was a username associated with the process, so I added this line as well:

```
psi.UserName = Environment.UserName;
```

Now I'm getting "the stub received bad data"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got back to working on this and figured out how to get this to work.

I had to specifically set the Username, Password, and Domain of the Process.ProcessStartInfo in order for the process to execute.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true):

> **Cmd**
>
> Starts a new instance of the command interpreter, Cmd.exe. Used
>   without parameters, cmd displays Windows XP version and copyright
>   information.
>
> Syntax cmd [[{/c|/k}] [/s] [/q] [/d] [{/a|/u}] [/t:fg]
>   [/e:{on|off}] [/f:{on|off}] [/v:{on|off}] string] Top of page
>
> **Parameters**
>
> /c : Carries out the command specified by string and then
>   stops.

So you need to:

1. Pass the full path to the EXE or
2. [Set the working directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) to the directory containing the exe

then

1. Make `processFile` == "[]csvde.exe", and remove it from `processArguments`, or
2. Prepent "/c \"" and append "\"" to `processArguments`.

Comment: Option 1 results: Error, the system cannot find the file specified. Option 2 results: Error, 'csvde' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Edited option one.  For both options, you need to set the working directory to one containing "csvde.exe" or add the full path to the exe.

Comment: Wow, something's wrong with my machine. I navigated via Explorer to C:\Windows\System32, found csvde.exe, copied the name of the file, pasted in this bit of code and the message box said "no"....

            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\csvde.exe"))
                MessageBox.Show("yes");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("no");

Comment: That's a permissions issue.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx, "The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or **if the caller does not have permission to read the file.**" (emphasis mine). If you are going to run an application in System32, you need to run it as Administrator, which is a problem itself.

Comment: No, you aren't :-)  You are a member of the Administrators group, but unless you right click on an executable and click "Run as Administrator", you don't have a user token with Admin credentials.  I'd bet that if you navigate to C:\Windows\System32\csvde.exe and double click on csvde.exe, you'll get the UAP dialog box before it runs.

Comment: my bad. I tried double-clicking the csvde.exe and the screen "blipped", but the UAP box (or anything else for that matter) did not come up. I also added the "runas" to the ProcessStartInfo.Verb property and I'm still seeing the same error message. Here's what it looks like right now: WorkingDirectory = C:\..\System32, Filename = C:\..\System32\cmd.exe and the arguments = /C "csvde.exe -s {servername} -f {OutputFilename} -d {OUPath} -r {RowFilter} -n". There are quotes after the /C and at the very end of the arguments, AND there are quotes around the OutputFilename as well as the RowFilter.

Comment: What happens if you open cmd.exe and run the same thing (quotes and all) via command line?

Comment: I first tried this: /C \"csvde.exe -s testdmzdc01.dot.testdmz.lan -f \"C:\\temp\\ADExport\\p.csv\" -d OU=Users,OU=ARTS,DC=dot,DC=countydmz,DC=lan -r \"(objectClass=user)\" -n\" and it returned "/C is not recognized.......", so I removed that and tried again with this "csvde.exe -s testdmzdc01.dot.testdmz.lan -f \"C:\\temp\\ADExport\\p.csv\" -d OU=Users,OU=ARTS,DC=dot,DC=countydmz,DC=lan -r \"(objectClass=user)\" -n". That looks like it logged in ok, but then said "No Entries found". Does that have to do with the extra backslashes for the quotes?

Comment: Also, when I open the command prompt, the title says: "Administrator: Command Prompt". When go to properties of cmd.exe, it's grayed out so I can't un-check "Run this program as an administrator" even though it's not already checked.

Comment: Do I need to throw the /S option out there as well since I have double-quotes inside the double-quotes?

Comment: No, I mean *from the command line*, run `cmd.exe /C \"csvde.exe -s testdmzdc01.dot.testdmz.lan -f \"C:\\temp\\ADExport\\p.csv\" -d OU=Users,OU=ARTS,DC=dot,DC=countydmz,DC=lan -r \"(objectClass=user)\" -n\"`  That will simulate what you are doing from .NET.

Comment: What happens if you first execute a `cd Windows\System32`?

Comment: P:\>C:

C:\>cd Windows\System32

C:\Windows\System32>cmd.exe /C \"csvde.exe -s testdmzdc01.dot.testdmz.lan -f \"C:\\temp\\ADExport\\p.csv\" -d OU=Users,O
U=ARTS,DC=dot,DC=testdmz,DC=lan -r \"(objectClass=user)\" -n\"
'\"csvde.exe -s testdmzdc01.dot.testdmz.lan -f \"C:\\temp\\ADExport\\p.csv\" -d OU=Users,OU=ARTS,DC=dot,DC=testdmz,DC=la
n -r \"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Anyone know of another way to see why I'm getting the error in the line above?

Comment: here's the output of the command you requested in "No, I mean from the command line, run..."

P:\>cmd.exe /C "csvde.exe -s testdmzdc01.dot.testdmz.lan -f "C:\temp\ADExport\p.csv" -d OU=Users,OU=ARTS,DC=dot,DC=testd
mz,DC=lan -r "(objectClass=user)" -n"
Connecting to "testdmzdc01.dot.testdmz.lan"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Exporting directory to file C:\temp\ADExport\p.csv
Searching for entries...
Writing out entries
......................
Export Completed. Post-processing in progress...
228 entries exported

The command has completed successfully